# AWS Wrangler Athena and S3 read_csv UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to use awswrangler's s3.read_csv function to read an Athena SQL query output. The output path is `wr.athena.get_query_execution(query_execution_id)`. I can confirm that the output path exists. I then load the output using awswrangler's `wr.s3.read_csv(outputpath)` function. However, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position`.

```
df = wr.s3.read_csv(<s3path.csv>)

--snipped--
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 711, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2034, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 75: invalid start byte
```

Side note, I am trying to avoid wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql) because I am implementing a asynchronous function.

I tried to download the s3 object using boto3.s3_client, read the file and loaded it via pandas.read_csv() directly and works perfectly. So, I don't think it's a permission issue nor a corrupt file issue. Any idea what I am doing wrong with wr.s3.read_csv() call?

Comment: can you try passing encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' in your read_csv as in df = wr.s3.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding

Comment: Prabhakar Reddy, I'm ran into the same problem. I added the encoding='ISO-8859-1' which allows me to read in the data as a dataframe but there is always an extra column with a random name such as 0201017_081503_00051_xa9cu"5

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I also get the extra column with a random name.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, probably you're reading metadata file. If you're tring to read the output of Athena query, you should consider Athena creates metadata file. So maybe you have something like this:

```
s3://BUCKET/prefix/4a21ada3-d1d0-467e-907d-9abf5f0bb69c.csv.metadata
s3://BUCKET/prefix/4a21ada3-d1d0-467e-907d-9abf5f0bb69c.csv
```

If you're using with this code:

```
path = s3://BUCKET/prefix/4a21ada3-d1d0-467e-907d-9abf5f0bb69c.csv

wr.s3.read_csv(path)
```

you'll read two files, also metadata file, because metadata file has the same name until .metadata.

So the solution to this problem is use `path_suffix` argument.

```
wr.s3.read_csv(path, path_suffix='csv')
```

Comment: THIS IS SUPERB!!!!!